# How to define metric in the Space of Holomorphic Functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I am looking for a proper way to define distane on the space of Holomorphic functions defined on a domain $D$.Does the Montel's Theorem (Given below from Stein's Book) helps to Characterize Compact Sets in the space of Holomorphic function with this distace ?

**Montel's** Theorem States That:

**Theorem:**  Suppose $F$ be a family of holomorphic functions defined on a domain $D$  which is uniformly bounded on every compact subset of $D$.Then:

1.The family $F$ is equicontinuous on every compact subset of $D$

2.The Family $F$ is normal.

Please help.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

The space of analytic functions is a subspace of the space of continuous functions. The metric on this space is defined as follows.

If $G$ is an open set in $\mathbb C$, exhaust $G$ by a sequence of compact sets. Define $\rho_n = \sup \{ d(f(z), g(z)):z\in K_n\}$. Then we can define the metric as $$\rho (f,g) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^n \frac {\rho_n (f,g)}{1+\rho_n (f,g)}$$.

Source: Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable.

Comment: Thank you ! Does Montel's theorem helps to Characterize Compact sets with this metric?

Comment: In Conway, the theorem is stated a little differently. Here, it says that $\mathfrak {F}$ is normal if and only if $\mathfrak {F}$ is locally bounded. The way I think about this is as a kind of analog to Heine Borel. From this interpretation, it is clear that a set in $\mathfrak {F}$ is compact if it is closed and locally bounded.

Comment: First you need to show that convergence in this metric is equivalent to uniform convergence on compact sets. Then you need to recall how to complete this sentence: "A metric space is complete if and only if every sequence..."